Worm fanfic involving Aisha, Missy, and maybe Dinah as scouts investigating a magic mystery
I think I read this 2-3 years ago, probably on either the Sufficient Velocity or Space Battles forums. The protagonists are three of the younger characters in the series, all lacking their usual powers (at least as I recall it). They're some form of scout, I think not actually Girl Scouts, and they're seeking to get a merit badge involving solving a local mystery. To that end, they start exploring graffiti or gang tags in Brockton Bay, focusing on a particular symbol, or set of symbols, that don't match to any of the local gangs. This eventually leads to them winding up in New York, following the path of the symbols, where I think they run into a safehouse for The Adepts, as well as some kind of a ceiling mural in a subway where something involving malign glyphs starts up until Legend arrives and manages to zap it. I remember them talking to him afterwards, and him offhand mentioning his husband by name in the context that, once he got the girls to safety, he needed to be home for dinner and his own children. Despite the situation, the girls were undeterred in their plan to solve the mystery.
Overall, the story had a degree of "crack fic" with the children throwing themselves into incredibly dangerous situations in pursuit of the merit badge with no real understanding of how much danger they were in and their canon personalities being extremely exaggerated, but that the overall setting was significantly more eldritch than the usual setting, with an implication that there was real magic involved, rather than the "powers working like magic beliefs" in canon Worm.

I found the correct combination of search terms. It is The Adventures of the Young Missy Biron and Aisha Laborn, Girl Guides Extraordinaire! by Grist.

Follow Missy Biron, age ten, and Aisha Laborn, age eleven, as they work at earning badges and incidentally and accidentally discover and uncover all kind of things not wanting to be discovered, let alone uncovered.

Searching Spacebattles for girl scout aisha missy turned up someone else helping a seeker, providing a link. I haven't found Dinah showing up yet, but the situation is started by Missy seeking a badge.

All she needed now was a mystery to look into for her investigation badge. According to the regulations investigating a mystery wasn't strictly necessary, but let's be honest here: Starting to merely meet the requirements now would be half hearted.

She recruits Aisha, as well as two original characters, as their team, and they do submit their report to get the badge at the end of the first (and so far only) arc.
